# kubernetes sidecar not working(InitContainerRestartPolicyForbidden)

Tags: kubernetes, sidecar

I want to make sidecar container

・my kubernetes version

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: v1.28.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.28.6
```

・pod yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sidecar
spec:
  initContainers:
  - command:
    - tail
    - -f
    - /dev/null
    image: alpine
    name: sidecar
    restartPolicy: Always
  containers:
  - image: alpine
    name: main
    command:
    - tail
    - -f
    - /dev/null
```

I enabled the SidecarContainers feature　gates as below
・Add 「--feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true」 to 「kube-*.yaml」

```
$ sudo grep feature /etc/kubernetes/manifests/*
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml:    - --feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml:    - --feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml:    - --feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true
```

・Also added to 10-kubeadm.conf

Even if I applied each one of the two lines at the bottom that are commented out, I failed to create a sidecar container.

```
# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
#KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true
#Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true"
```

but, When I deploy a pod, it becomes InitContainerRestartPolicyForbidden and I don't know the reason.

```
$ kubectl get pod sidecar
NAME      READY   STATUS                                RESTARTS   AGE
sidecar   0/2     InitContainerRestartPolicyForbidden   0          2m52s


$ kubectl describe pod sidecar |tail -5
Events:
  Type     Reason                               Age    From               Message
  ----     ------                               ----   ----               -------
  Warning  InitContainerRestartPolicyForbidden  3m24s  kubelet            Init container "sidecar" may not have a non-default restartPolicy
  Normal   Scheduled                            3m24s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/sidecar to choi-k8s-test-node
```

Can somebody help me on this?
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you didn't actually enable SidecarContainers feature gate for kubelet. Can you paste your /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf file?

Comment: @VasiliiAngapov
thanks for comment. I edited the contents of 10-kubeadm.conf in the main text.

Comment: Yeah, it appears the SidecarContainers feature gate isn't enabled in the kubelet. Your pod manifest runs fine in my test cluster (v1.28). Perhaps your kubelet configuration is being overridden. 
Anyway, you can confirm what feature gates are enabled on a node by running `kubectl get --raw "/api/v1/nodes/<NODENAME>/proxy/configz" | jq`
Don't forget to replace <NODENAME> with the actual worker node name

Comment: @William
```kubectl get --raw "/api/v1/nodes/<NODENAME>/proxy/configz" | jq```
I checked the above command, but I didn't see any sidecar-related settings. How can I activate the kubelet?

Comment: To rule out any misconfiguration or hidden overwrites, pass it as part of the kubelet argument in your `ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet ...........  --feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true`. Afterall, feature gates specified as command line arguments have the highest precendence when kubelet is reading configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I solved this problem. I added the solution to the body content

Answer (score 1):

*(Moved this from the user's question to an answer):*

I solved it by creating a sidecar using the following method:

1. (in worker node)edit /var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env

```
$ vi /var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env

KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS="--container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --pod-infra-container-image=registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9"
↓
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS="--container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --pod-infra-container-image=registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9 --feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true"
```

2. (in worker node)restart kubelet

```
systemctl restart kubelet
```

3. (in master node)Add 「--feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true」 to 「/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-*.yaml」

```
$ sudo grep feature /etc/kubernetes/manifests/*
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml:    - --feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml:    - --feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml:    - --feature-gates=SidecarContainers=true
```

4. (in master node)check that SidecarContainers are enabled

```
$ kubectl get --raw "/api/v1/nodes/<worker node name>/proxy/configz" | jq |grep -i -e side -e feat
    "featureGates": {
      "SidecarContainers": true
```